# How to select with jq in an array of values?

Tags: select, syntax, jq, tacit-programming

I want to select elements >= 3 in an array like `[2, 4, 3]` with `jq`, how do I do it?

I have found answers when the array contains objects (e.g `[{Name:"a", Age:2} ...]}`) with things like `select (.Age >= 2)` but I don't know how to refer to values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.`.

If you want to retain the array structure, you could use `map(select(_))`, e.g.

```
jq -n '[2, 4, 3] | map(select(. >= 3))'
```

If you just want the values, you could consider:

```
jq '.[] | select(. >= 3)' <<< '[2, 4, 3]'
```

Comment: works! I had good intuition actually and tried the `.` but didn't use `map`. Why does it work only with `map` ? I have seen `select` work alone before

Comment: See the def of select at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedolan/jq/master/src/builtin.jq